# javascript - How would I get every possible pattern in a string?

Tags: javascript, parsing, discord

I'm creating a Discord bot that keeps track of words and phrases that everyone types into the chat. For example, I would like my program to take in the sentence `This is a sentence` and put it into an array with all possible patterns of words, i.e.

`['This', 'This is', 'This is a', 'This is a sentence', 'is', 'is a', 'is a sentence' ... ]`

Essentially it should start with the first word (space delimited) and get every pattern for the rest of the sentence. Then move onto the next word and do the same thing.

I figure I could do this with a simple `for` loop, but I'm worried about longer sentences and multiple people typing in the chat having an impact on the speed and accuracy of this bot. Is there a better way or a built in JS function that I could use to implement this in my bot?

Comment: What is the purpose? The number of  combinations is *O(n²)*

Comment: to add to what @trincot is asking, if this is for pattern recognition, perhaps regex is better suited

Comment: @CorvusCrypto yes this is for pattern recognition. Basically to see how many times a user has said a specific word or phrase. I can use regex, but would something other than a `for` loop be better suited for this task?

Comment: yes. You can use javascript's builtin Regex functionality for this and Regex can run this search in O(n) time and return an array of all matches with which you can just use the length attribute. Just off the top of my head here.

Comment: @NickMartini For phrase recognition, just limit the length of the pattern. That'll still give you enough performance, assuming you use proper lookup structures for the actual matching phase.

Comment: @CorvusCrypto Regex rarely runs in `O(n)`.

Comment: @Bergi so you're saying only capture patterns that are, say, three or less words in length?

Comment: @NickMartini Whatever you consider the maximum length of a "phrase", yes.